# How To Create Dynamic FormGroups for Sections and check each section if form is valid

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I have Multiple Sections Each Containing Subsections and inside I have Questions that I need to validate, The Thing is:

I have a save button for each section.

Edit: I Don't know how many Sections I will have from Api and how many Subsections or Questions its all dynamic

how do I make:
FormGroup for each Subsection. and inside Subsections I have array of questions(fields) that I need to have FormControls for.
what I want to achieve is: SectionForm1.isValid save();, SectionForm2.isValid save()...

[sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtYrC.png)

I've tried doing this.
but it adds formControl for all fields.
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder-fqhyvh?file=app%2Fdynamic-form-builder%2Fdynamic-form-builder.module.ts,app%2Fdynamic-form-builder%2Ffield-builder%2Ffield-builder.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my issue

Parent Component

```
 this.applicationService.applicationSearch().subscribe((data: any) => {
  data.data.sections.forEach((section: Sections) => {
    //  console.log(section);
    this.sectionsData$.push({
      id: section.id,
      name: section.name,
      order: section.order,
      completed: section.completed,
      subsections: section.subsections,
    });
    this.sortedSections = this.sectionsData$.sort(
      (a, b) => a.order - b.order
    );
  });
  this.form = new FormGroup({}) as FormGroup;

  this.sectionsData$.forEach((s: Sections) => {
    this.form.addControl(s.name, new FormGroup({})) ;
    const section = this.form.get(s.name) as FormGroup;

    s.subsections.forEach((sub: Subsection) => {
      section.addControl(sub.name, new FormGroup({}));
      const subsection = section.get(sub.name) as FormGroup; 

      sub.questions.forEach((q: Question) => {
        if(q.type == 'Checkbox'){
          subsection.addControl(q.name, new FormGroup({}))
          q.options.forEach(option => {
            (subsection.get(q.name) as FormGroup).addControl(option.answer, new FormControl(false))
          })
          
        }else{
          subsection.addControl(q.name, new FormControl('', q.required ? Validators.required : null)) 
        }
      })
    })
  });
});
```

Parent Component HTML

```
 <div *ngFor="let section of sectionsData$; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="this.queryId == section.id">
   <div *ngIf="!!sectionsData$" class="details-form">
      <mat-stepper [orientation]="(stepperOrientation | async)!" #stepper>
        <mat-step *ngFor="let subsection of section.subsections" [label]="subsection.name" [stepControl]="form.get(section.name).get(subsection.name)" style="overflow: unset;">
          <app-details
            [formGroup]="form.get(section.name).get(subsection.name)"
            [subsections]="subsection.name"
            [fields]="subsection.questions"
          ></app-details>
          <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
          </div>
        </mat-step>
      </mat-stepper>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Child component

```
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input() subsections: any;
  @Input() fields: any[] = [];
```

Child Component HTML

```
    <div *ngIf="formGroup">
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup" fxFlexAlign.xs="end">
    <div
      class="row"
      fxLayout="row"
      fxLayout.xs="column"
      fxFlexFill
      fxLayoutAlign="center center"
    >
      <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
        <field-builder
          *ngIf="formGroup"
          [field]="field"
          [form]="formGroup"
        ></field-builder>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then I send My Forms To a Form Builder Component

```
 @Input() field: any;
  @Input() form: any;

  get isValid() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].valid;
  }
  get isDirty() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].dirty;
  }
```

Form Builder Component HTML

```
<div *ngIf="!!form" class="details-form">
    <div class="row" [formGroup]="form">
      <!-- <strong class="text-danger" *ngIf="field.required && form.get(field.name).invalid">*</strong> -->
      <div class="col-sm col-md col-lg" [ngSwitch]="field.type" >
        <textbox *ngSwitchCase="'Text'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></textbox>
        <textareas *ngSwitchCase="'TextArea'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></textareas>
        <description *ngSwitchCase="'Description'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></description>
        <dropdown *ngSwitchCase="'SelectBox'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></dropdown>
        <checkbox *ngSwitchCase="'Checkbox'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></checkbox>
        <yesno *ngSwitchCase="'YesNo'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></yesno>
        <radio *ngSwitchCase="'SingleSelect'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></radio>
        <file *ngSwitchCase="'file'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></file>
        <date *ngSwitchCase="'Date'" [field]="field" [form]="form.get(field.name)"></date>
        <div class="alert alert-danger my-1 p-2 fadeInDown animated" *ngIf="!isValid && isDirty">{{field.name}} is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After That I send Them to Field Types component based on What Type I Need

TextBox Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'textbox',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="form">
      <div class="col-sm col-md col-lg">
        <mat-form-field
        appearance="outline"
        #textbox
        fxLayout="row"
        fxLayout.xs="column"
        >
        <mat-label>{{field.name}}</mat-label>
          <input
            #textbox
            matInput
            [attr.type]="field.type"
            [id]="field.name"
            [name]="field.name"
            [formControl]="form"
            [placeholder]="field.name"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./input-types.shared.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TextBoxComponent {
  @Input() field: any = {};
  @Input() form: FormControl;
  get isValid() {
    return this.form.valid;
  }
  get isDirty() {
    return this.form.dirty;
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make components inside Forms you should create custom FormControls (you can read [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/))

If you want a snippet to check if every control is valid you can do as follows:

```
checkValidity(): void {
  const findInvalidControls = () => {
    const invalid = [];
    const controls = ...this.form.controls;

    for (const name in controls) {
      if ((controls as any)[name]?.invalid) {
        invalid.push(name);
      }
    }
    return invalid;
  };

  const invalid = findInvalidControls();

  // Do something if "invalid.length" is > 0
}
```

In order for this to work, you have to make sure that when you create a FormControl, you set some validators, for example:

In your component.ts:

```
private control = new FormControl('') // Initialize the control with a value. Can be a value of '' if it's a string

private control = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]) // Set the validators in your control

private control = new FormControl<string>('', [Validators.required]) // Take advantages of typed FormControls
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of how I handled large forms with different sections and logic in a large project. Not sure, if it fits to your problem.

Create a parent component and a Subsection Component for each subsection including a own formgroup, save logic, etc.

```html
<!-- Parent Component HTML -->
<subsection1-form #subsection1Form></subsection1-form>
<subsection2-form #subsection2Form></subsection2-form>
```

```js
// Parent Component TS
@ViewChild('subsection1Form') subsection1Form: Subsection1FormComponent;
@ViewChild('subsection2Form') subsection2Form: Subsection2FormComponent;

/** Call this method to save all subsections */
save() {
  this.subsection1Form.form.markAllAsTouched();
  this.subsection2Form.form.markAllAsTouched();

  if (this.subsection1Form.valid && this.subsection2Form.valid ) {
    forkJoin([
      this.subsection1Form.submit(),
      this.subsection2Form.submit()
    ]).subscribe(/* ... */);
  }
}
```

I also created a simple interface for SubsectionForms and let the subsection components implement it.

```js
export interface SubsectionForm {
  /** Make a request and return the response if it is successful. On errors return 
  Overservable<never>. */
    submit(): Observable<any>;
  }
}
```

And the SubsectionComponent would look like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'subsection1-form',
  templateUrl: './subsection1-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subsection1-form.component.scss']
})
export class Subsection1FormComponent implements OnInit, SubsectionForm {

  @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;

  submit(): Observable<any> {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

This way, the subsections business logic is nicely encapsuled.

I think this is also pretty flexible:

- Subsections can also returns anything else. Doesn't need to return an Observable.
- You can add more validation either in subsections directly or in parent component if it is "cross-subsection" logic

For dynamic Forms you can replace the subsection components with a dynamic FormGroup-array.

```js
// Parent Component TS
subsections: FormGroup[];

initializeSubsections(): void {
  // However, create/initialize/update the different forms dynamically
}

/** Call this method to save all subsections */
save() {
  this.subsections.forEach((form: FormGroup) => form.markAllAsTouched());

  if (this.subsections.every(({ valid }: FormGroup) => valid)) {
    // Do something with your subsections
  }
}
```

Maybe you can combine it, if you can create a generic subsection component.

```html
<!-- in Parent Component HTML -->
<!-- you can also create a more complex array with additional input parameters, not only the formGroup -->
<subsection-component *ngFor="let form in subsections; index as i" [form]="form" (submit)="submit(i)"></subsection-component>
```

```js
// Added in Parent Component TS
submit(index: number) {
  if (this.subsections[i].valid) {
    // Do something with subsection i
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Marcel, Thanks for Answering, the thing is all my data is dynamic, basically it can change anytime and I don't know the changes.  I currently have 3 sections but next time I may have more, same with the Subsections and the questions inside them

Comment: Then you can simply replace the subsection forms with an formgroup-array in the parent component. Similar to what @Pietro Lungarini wrote. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As i see you are using child component .To fix this issue .Firstly you have to use  ControlvalueAccessor in your child component. [click here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor&ved=2ahUKEwiM5NuKiMf7AhVr8XMBHfkvD8QQFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0LLOTo6YUItKg13zLtw0hP)  . Here is eg. how to use this [click here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-form-group&ved=2ahUKEwjojvixicf7AhXyF7cAHbIQDjAQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3FFL3_IY3G_NhmnaweZsb2)